# vue-persistedstate reducer with path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

im using vue-persistedstate with specific modules to be set persisted only, and it's working well using `path` attribute.

but when i try to mix it with `reducer`, the modules set in the `path` is not working anymore and reducer set all modules persisted. how should i do with reducer?

```js
const persistedstate = new createPersistedState({
  key: "newsportal-vuex",
  storage: window.localStorage, 
  paths: ["auth", "venues", "play", "playWS", "purchaseSettings"], // only the persisted ones
  reducer(val) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("newsportal_isuseracceptcookie")) {
      // DONT USE PERSISTEDSTATE IF USER DECLINE COOKIES
      return {};
    }
    return val; // <-this return ALL MODULES. i want to set only modules in path
  }
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This makes sense because a reducer is able to fully replace path functionality. It can be seen that it has default reducer implementation that handles paths, https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/blob/master/src/index.ts#L57

Answer (score 0):

just realised i need to rebuild the object

```js
reducer(val, paths) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("newsportal_isuseracceptcookie")) {
      // DONT USE PERSISTEDSTATE IF USER DECLINE COOKIES
      return {};
    }

    // make persisted state as in paths
    let reducer = {};

    Object.entries(val).forEach(entry => {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      if (paths.includes(key)) {
        reducer[key] = value;
      }
    });

    return reducer;
  }
```